# Codeigniter: populate form with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'm a student from Belgium and for a project from school, I have to make a calendar with events in codeigniter. I already made some bootstrap modals to make the forms to add new events or edit existing ones. The add functionality already works but now I have some troubles with the edit form. I want to populate my form with the existing data from the database. My teacher showed me quick how I can do this with jquery.

**this is my main view:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#editButton').click(function() { 
        day_data = $(this).find('#eventp').html();
        $.get('http://localhost/TEDXPXL/mycal/editEvent/'+encodeURI(day_data), function(data){$('#editNaam').val(data); $('#editBeginuur').val()});
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="editNaam" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="editNaam" class="required col-sm-2 col-lg-10" id="editNaam" /> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="editBeginuur" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start&nbsp;time:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="time" name="editBeginuur" class="required col-sm-2 col-lg-3" id="editBeginuur"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

day_data will find the name of the event that will appear in the header of my bootstrap modal, so I can use this in my where clause to get the data from the database.

**This is my controller function**

```
function editEvent() {                  
        $naam = urldecode(func_get_args()[0]);
        $this->load->model("mycal_model");
        $data = array();
        $data['naam'] = $this->mycal_model->fill_edit_form($naam)["naam"];
        $data['beginuur'] = $this->mycal_model->fill_edit_form($naam)["beginuur"];
        $data['einduur'] = $this->mycal_model->fill_edit_form($naam)["einduur"];
        $data['commentaar'] = $this->mycal_model->fill_edit_form($naam)["commentaar"];
        $this->load->view("fillform.php", $data);
    }
```

**And this is the fillform view:**

```
<?php 
  print $naam;
  print $beginuur;
  print $einduur;
  print $commentaar;
?>
```

These 4 elements are returned as 'data' in the function in the $.get form my main view. But when I set the value from my 'editNaam' element, it looks like "eventNameeventStartTimeeventEndTimeeventComment", which is normal of course.
But how can I split the 'data' in 4 elements so that editNaam only has the eventName, editBeginuur the event Start Time etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got the question right, but from what I can understand you want to be able to edit those four values right $naam, $beginuur, $einduur, and $commentar? If so maybe this can help

**Fillform view**

```
<?php echo form_open($insert_function_url); ?>
Label 1: <?php echo form_input('naam', $naam); ?><br>
Label 2: <?php echo form_input('beginuur', $beginuur); ?><br>
Label 3: <?php echo form_input('einduur', $einduur); ?><br>
Label 4: <?php echo form_input('commentaar', $commentaar); ?><br>
<button> Save </button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

did i get this right? hope this helps. Have a nice day.